# Getting lost trying to use Cauchy-Euler method on a problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation:
$$
dy/dx = y^2 - (y/x) - (4/x^2)
$$
Originally, I thought this would behave as a Ricatti ODE, but I have realized that when I view it, it can be solved as a Cauchy-Euler. I have gotten:
$$
P(x) = -4/x^2\\
Q(x) = -1/x\\
R(x) = 1
$$
I'm having confusion when applying this equation:
$$
m^2 + (a-1)m + b = 0
$$
The a value would be -1, but when I continue this to completion I cannot reach the answer provided which is:
$$
y = 2/x + 4x^3/(C-x^4)
$$
The 2/x is a first solution and was given. The remaining solution is attained by using:
$$
y = v'(x)/vR(x)
$$
I have all the pieces, but I am having trouble making that final step to end up with $v(x) = -x^4 + C$.

Looking for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a classification problem. Euler-Cauchy is foremost a class of linear DE, but you have a quadratic part in your correctly classified Riccati equation.

What you can do is parametrize solutions as $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$ and get
$$
0=u''+\frac{u'}{x}-\frac{4u}{x^2 }
$$
which now is linear and indeed Euler-Cauchy with characteristic polynomial $m^2-4=0$, so $u=Ax^2+Bx^{-2}$,...

---

Looking back at your derivation, you apparently had this mechanism in the background, and just had some problem extracting the coefficients with the correct sign. It should be $y=-\frac{v'}{Rv}$ or you should have had $R=-1$.

That's one reason I prefer to do these calculations from first principles, for me it is easier to remember the (principles of the) tricks that are used than the schemata that are derived from them.

Comment: I see! Thank you for this, putting it in terms of the u's was something that admittedly I should have thought of. Thank you!